# SQL error with variable assignment, concat, and right

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate an ID by concatenating bits from a few cells in a MySQL table. I want t0 get rid of - and : and only have digits in the ID. I get a syntax error with the following:

```
update scan_data
set @scanDate1 = replace(scanDate,'-','')
set @scanTime1 = replace(scanTime,'-','')
scanID = concat(right(scanContent,2),right(@scanDate1,2),right(@scanTime1,2))
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update scan_data set scanID = concat(right(scanContent, 2),
                                     right(replace(scanDate,'-',''), 2),
                                     right(replace(scanTime,'-',''), 2)
                                    );
```